# Settings.Default.Settings.Save() is writing blank values to the settings file in the users appdatafolder

Tags: c#, settings

I'm having an issue with the c# settings file, it appears to be writing the user scoped settings to a file, but it actually just writes.

```
<SettingName>
  <value />
</SettingName>
```

Which is not what I'm setting it to in the code. Any idea of why this might be failing? It's not throwing an exception at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase class is a bit finicky about how it serializes complex data types. If the class is not marked as serializable it will throw an exception, but on conditions where there would be serialization error (say, a circular reference in the class, or dictionary exists as part of the class), the settings system swallows that exception and writes an empty value.

You can use the xml serializer, which will throw an exception, to test for this condition. Simply at the same place you attempt to save your settings, also attempt to serialize your object. If that serialization throws an exception, then you would expect the settings system to fail, otherwise it's a different issue.